# Dynamically modify symbol table at runtime (in C)

Tags: symbols, elf, ld-preload

Is it possible to dynamically modify symbol table at runtime in C (in elf format on Linux)?

My eventual goal is the following:

Inside certain function say `foo`, I want to override `malloc` function to my custom handler `my_malloc`. But outside `foo`, any `malloc` should still call to malloc as in glibc.

Note: this is different from `LD_PRELOAD` which would override `malloc` during the entire program execution.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to dynamically modify symbol table at runtime in C (in elf format on Linux)?

In theory this is possible, but in practice it's too hard to do.

> Inside certain function say `foo`, I want to override `malloc` function to my custom handler `my_malloc`. But outside `foo`, any `malloc` should still call to `malloc` as in glibc.

Modifying symbol table (even if it were possible) would *not* get you to your desired goal.

*All* calls from *anywhere* inside your ELF binary (let's assume `foo` is in the main executable), resolve to the *same* PLT import slot `malloc@plt`. That slot is resolved to glibc `malloc` on the first call (from anywhere in your program, assuming you are not using `LD_BIND_NOW=1` or similar). After that slot has been resolved, any further modification to the symbol table will have *no effect*.

You didn't say how much control over `foo` you have.

If you can recompile it, the problem becomes trivial:

```
#define malloc my_malloc
int foo() {
  // same code as before
}
#undef malloc
```

If you are handed a precompiled `foo.o`, you are linking it with `my_malloc.o`, and you want to redirect all calls from inside `foo.o` from `malloc` to `my_malloc`, that's actually quite simple to do at the object level (i.e. before final link).

All you have to do is go through `foo.o` relocation records, and change the ones that say "put address of external `malloc` here" to "put address of external `my_malloc` here".

If `foo.o` contains additional functions besides `foo`, it's quite simple to limit the relocation rewrite to just the relocations inside `foo`.

Comment: >  change the ones that say "put address of external malloc here" to "put address of external my_malloc here". 


Any tool, say gcc, that can do this?

Comment: I know it's a very old answer, but we need to change the symbols tables in runtime too, but in our case it is to replace the malloc on dynamically loaded libraries, is there a way to do it?

Comment: @GuyKorland You should ask a separate question, clearly stating your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to dynamically modify symbol table at runtime in C (in elf format on Linux)?

Yes, it is not easy, but the functionality can be packaged into a library, so at the end of the day, it can be made practical.

### Typemock Isolator++

(https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page/isolate-pp/)

This is free-to-use, but closed source solution. The usage example from documentation should be instructive

```
TEST_F(IsolatorPPTests, IsExpired_YearIs2018_ReturnTrue) {

 Product product;

 // Prepare a future time construct
 tm* fakeTime = new tm();
 fakeTime->tm_year = 2018;

 // Fake the localtime method
 FAKE_GLOBAL(localtime);

 // Replace the returned value when the method is called 
 // with the fake value.
 WHEN_CALLED(localtime(_)).Return(fakeTime);

 ASSERT_TRUE(product.IsExpired());
}
```

### Other libraries of this kind

- [Mimick](https://github.com/Snaipe/Mimick), from Q: [Function mocking in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677778/function-mocking-in-c)
- [cpp-stub](https://github.com/coolxv/cpp-stub), from Q: [Creating stub functionality in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238520/creating-stub-functionality-in-c)
- [Elfspy](https://github.com/mollismerx/elfspy), for C++, but sometimes it's OK to test C code from C++ unittests, from Q: [C++ mock framework capable of mocking non-virtual methods and C functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898706/c-mock-framework-capable-of-mocking-non-virtual-methods-and-c-functions)
- HippoMocks, from Q: [Mocking C functions in MSVC (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615983/mocking-c-functions-in-msvc-visual-studio)
- the subprojects in https://github.com/coolxv/cpp-stub/tree/master/other
- ... there is still more, feel free to append ...

### Alternate approaches

- ld's --wrap option and linker scripts, https://gitlab.com/hedayat/powerfake
- various approaches described in answers for Q: [Advice on Mocking System Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924440/advice-on-mocking-system-calls)
- and in answers to Q: [How to mock library calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686897/how-to-mock-library-calls)

### Rewrite code to make it testable

This is easier in other languages than C, but still doable even in C. Structure code into small functions without side-effects that can be unit-tested without resorting to trickery, and so on. I like this blog [Modularity. Details. Pick One.](https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/modularity-details-pick-one) about the tradeoffs this brings. Personally, I guturally dislike the "sea of small functions and tons of dependency injection" style of code, but I realize that that's the easiest to work with, all things considered.

### Excursion to other languages

What you are asking for is trivial to do in Python, with the [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), or possibly by just assigning the mock into the original function directly, and undoing that at the end of the test.

In Java, there is Mockito/[PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock), which can be used to [replace static methods](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) for the duration of a test. Static methods in Java approximately correspond to regular functions in C.

In Go, there is [Mockey](https://github.com/bytedance/mockey), which works similarly to what needs to be done in C. It has similar limitations in that inlining can break this kind of runtime mocking. I am not sure if in C you can hit the issue that very short methods are unmockable because there is not enough space to inject the redirection code; I think more likely not, if all calls go through the Procedure Linkage Table.