# Dynamically add symbol into process symbol table

Tags: c, linux

How can I add a symbol to process symbol table dynamically on linux? For example, suppose I parse a script and determine that it has some methods which I then want to add into global address space so that they can be accessed by shared libraries loaded afterwards. What I then want to do is add a function pointer to a stub function that will call the script function and return the result (in C). But I want to say "add 'foo' pointing to &mygenericstub to global symbol table".. so when I then do dlopen() on an .so file with RTLD_GLOBAL flag, it will be able to call 'foo' as though it was a normal C function in the global namespace..

The idea is rather simple: to extend functionality of dynamic linker for that single process to also include names from scripts (but not just having an entry point function that takes a string argument for the script function to be called - but rather making the dynamic linking process transparent to other shared objects that may be loaded later). The idea would be not to modify existing table, but rather to map a new table as an extension to existing one (maybe this can somehow be done using mmap but I don't know what to map and how to extend it). Basically something similar to dlopen with the "global" option that works for dynamic names would be interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147018/dynamical-modify-symbol-table-at-runtime-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks quite cumbersome. You should probably change your code in order to lookup the symbol directly from your script interpreteur/VM.

but…

> suppose I parse a script and determine that it has some methods
>   which I then want to add into global address space so that they
>   can be accessed by shared libraries loaded afterwards.

AFAIK, there is no API exposed by the dynamic linker to register additional symbols. However, what you can is `dlopen` a new shared library whith those symbols:

1. dynamically generate `.so` file with a symbol for each function you want to expose;
2. each of those symbols reference a PLT-like pattern (the code fetch a GOT like entry and jump to it);
3. `dlopen` `RTLD_GLOBAL` this `.so` file;
4. fill the GOT-like variables;
5. you can now `dlopen` additional `.so` which will call to the PLT-like fuction and jump through the GOT-like variable to the real function.

Code of the shared object:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
foo:
    .cfi_startproc
    jmp *foo_got_alike(%rip)
    .cfi_endproc
.bss
    .align 8
    .type   foo_got_alike, @object
    .size   foo_got_alike, 8
foo_got_alike:
    .zero   8
```

This suppose you have managed to generate a suitable implementation for0 `foo` using some kind of JIT.