# How to mock non-virtual methods in c++ with gtest?

Tags: c++, mocking, tdd, bdd, fakeit

Is there a clean and easy way to mock non-virtual methods in c++ with gtest ? Despite using [the GoogleMock way](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods) that force you to re-declare your mocked class.

This feature is essential in my point of view to enable the full potential of BDD, TDD and mocking in c++. I'm using [FakeIt](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt) currently but I'm still encountering those difficulties :

- Testing code without having to use virtual methods
- Testing legacy code without impacting the current code

Edit :
I found [Injector++](https://github.com/mazong1123/injectorpp) and [isolate++](https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page/) that seems to be great solutions but not cross-plateform.

Comment: _"In this case, instead of sharing a common base class with the real class, **your mock class will be unrelated to the real class**, but contain methods with the same signatures. "_ - this is the _de facto_ way to mock non-virtual methods with Google Test/Mock. You could always write a generator for the mocked class, ideally based on reading the header of the class to be mocked e.g. using LLVM tools.

Comment: Another (imo worse) alternative is to using a macro, say `MOCKABLE`, that expands to nothing (empty) in release builds, but to `virtual` when you build your product for test, and use this to mark non-virtual methods you'd like to be easily mockable whilst in testing (note though that this would mean that you would actually be testing a different product implementation in test than in release).

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I'm more looking for a developer-friendly solution like [Injector++](https://github.com/mazong1123/injectorpp) or [isolate++](https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page/).

Comment: They seem to offer nice syntactic sugar for injections, but as for Gtest: no, this kind of brief solutions do not exist there (for non-virtual or static methods).

Comment: Does not yet integrate with gtest, but you might take a look at my PowerFake, introduced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682345/3936307

Comment: Update: Well, I finally put some time and added support for gmock too. Now it can be used with both gMock and FakeIt. But well, it only works with gcc & clang.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking non-virtual classes has been a pain for me from the start, I wanted to mock a class (both virtual and non-virtual methods) without touching the production code, so no templatizing or creating interfaces for each class.
This is how you can do it.

The trick is to replace the class of interest with a mock class.
So how to do it ?

Lets say you have a production class named `Production` and you want to test that class, but it depends on another class called `Dependency` which does not have an interface or virtual methods. You need to mock it in order to test `Production` class.

Within production.h after all include statements inject following code

```
#if TESTENV
    #include "DependencyMock.h"
    #define Dependency DependencyMock
#endif
```

So if `TESTENV` is defined and active, you will include the mocked version of the class and replace all usages of `Dependency` class in a file with a `DependencyMock` class.

DependencyMock.h will probably look something like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "Dependency.h"

class DependencyMock
{
public:
    void nonVirtualMethodToMock() {...};
    int methodToWrap() { return dep_.methodToWrap(); }
private:
    Dependency dep_;
};
```

You can mock any and all methods, but it might be easier and better to just wrap what you can.

Also there is minimum intrusion into production code .h file, and we are not really changing production code, we are only changing it when it is being tested.

So in my view only downside is that for this to work you need to recompile classes that you want to test in order to run the tests.

So this is the CmakeLists.txt example:

```
add_executable(testProduction  
    testProduction.cpp
    Production.cpp
    DependencyMock.cpp

)
target_link_libraries(testProduction PRIVATE
    ${PRODUCTION_DEPEND_LIBS}
    gtest_main
)
target_compile_definitions(testPoduction PRIVATE -DTESTENV=ON)
```

And you are good to go.

I don't know how this scales because I did not write that many tests but for now it is sufficient for me and by far the easiest way of all I have seen so far (I did not use any platforms like Isolator or Injector).
So hope this helps :)